# AutoMapper Stackoverflow error to start up API

Tags: c#, f#

I have a problem with AutoMapper when I wanna start up my API. I have the following types:

```cs
[<CLIMutable>]
type User = {
    [<BsonElement("_id")>]
    [<JsonProperty("id")>]
    Id : BsonObjectId

    [<BsonElement("email")>]
    [<JsonProperty("email")>]
    Email : string

    [<BsonElement("name")>]
    [<JsonProperty("name")>]
    Name : string

    [<BsonElement("password")>]
    [<JsonProperty("password")>]
    Password : string

    [<BsonElement("createdAt")>]
    [<JsonProperty("createdAt")>]
    [<BsonRepresentation(BsonType.DateTime)>]
    CreatedAt : DateTime

    [<BsonElement("updatedAt")>]
    [<JsonProperty("updatedAt")>]
    [<BsonRepresentation(BsonType.DateTime)>]
    UpdatedAt : DateTime
}

type UserDto = {
    [<JsonProperty("id")>]
    Id : BsonObjectId

    [<JsonProperty("email")>]
    Email : string

    [<JsonProperty("name")>]
    Name : string

    [<JsonProperty("createdAt")>]
    CreatedAt : DateTime

    [<JsonProperty("updatedAt")>]
    UpdatedAt : DateTime
}
```

Also I have the following to configure the AutoMapper

```cs
// AutoMapping.fs

type AutoMapping =
    inherit Profile

    new () as this = AutoMapping() then
        this.CreateMap<User, UserDto>() |> ignore

// AutoMapperExtensions.fs

module AutoMapperExtensions =

    type IServiceCollection with
    
        member this.AddMapperConfiguration(configuration: IConfiguration) =
            let mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(fun mc -> mc.AddProfile(new AutoMapping()))
            let mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper()
            
            this.AddSingleton(mapper) |> ignore
            this

// Startup.fs

member this.ConfigureServices(services: IServiceCollection) =
        services.AddLocalization(fun options -> options.ResourcesPath <- "Resources") |> ignore
        services.AddMapperConfiguration(this.Configuration) |> ignore
        // another instructions
```

But when I run the **dotnet run** command just it print the following error: **Stack overflow**
The problem is in the AutoMapping type, but I don't know if this is correct configured, that is, in C# it is like this:

```cs
public class AutoMapping : Profile
{
    public AutoMapping()
    {
        CreateMap<User, UserDto>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about AutoMapper, but the equivalent of your C# constructor is this:

```
type AutoMapping() as this =
    inherit Profile
    do this.CreateMap<User, UserDto>() |> ignore
```

Your code contains a secondary constructor that calls itself (resulting in stack overflow), but you don't need a secondary constructor at all in this case. Just create a primary constructor (by adding parens after the name of the type) and then initialize the object in a `do` statement.